# Why NodeJS doesn't parse the incoming HTML form data by default

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I want to know the underlying reason, why it's not the part of NodeJS built-in API to parse incoming form-data, as it's the very basic need of almost any web app.

I've tried searching the blog and asking the Ai tools like gpt, but still unable to understand at a very basic level, what's the underlying cause.
All I came to know is that, NodeJS team left the choice up to the developer to choose their own parsing middleware.

Comment: Do you mean [*Express*](https://expressjs.com/) instead of *Node*?

Comment: ummm.. that too, because even with ExpressJS, i can't parse the form-data, 
just need to understand the reason

Comment: It's probably pretty unlikely that someone from the Express development team would happen by and provide their original reasoning.  But *I suspect* it had to do with their intent to make a very small, very fast, otherwise unopinionated server.  Many web servers don't need this functionality.  So if it added any measurable overhead then it would have been extracted into an optional module so servers which don't need it don't have to include it.

Answer (score 0):

While Node.js does not provide built-in form data parsing, there are popular middleware modules like **body-parser** and **multer** that simplify this task for developers. This approach allows developers to customize their stack based on their specific needs, contributing to the flexibility of the Node.js ecosystem.